# Listview force scrolling to the top in flutter

Tags: android, ios, list, flutter, dart

Listview Code

```
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SizedBox();
        } else {
          return Container(
            margin: PHONE ? EdgeInsets.only(top:AppBar().preferredSize.height + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 90, bottom: 90)
            : EdgeInsets.only(top:AppBar().preferredSize.height + MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 140, bottom: 100),
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: data.length,
              addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                widget.animationController.forward();
                return AnimatedBuilder(
                  animation: widget.animationController,
                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                    return ProgramsTitleView(
                      animation: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
                        CurvedAnimation(
                          parent: widget.animationController,
                          curve: Interval((1 / data.length) * index, 1.0,
                              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
                        ),
                      ),
                      animationController: widget.animationController,
                      titleText: data[index]['Heading'],
                      type: widget.screen,
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
```

I have a listview which whose data is populated from http request. The weird thing about this is that it loads the data properly and scrolls down properly but if i scroll up a little bit, it force scrolls to the top no matter how far down i have scrolled before.
I looked everywhere but didn't find anybody with the same issue. Am i missing somethings which is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think it's better to use `StreamBuilder` instead of `FutureBuilder` since it only rebuilds the screen when there's change in data. So in your `getData()` function, you can add the data to `Stream` instead.

```dart
final controller = StreamController();

getData() async {
  final data = await _someCallToApi();
  controller.add(data);
}
```

Then listen to it in the UI:

```dart
 return StreamBuilder(
      stream: controller.stream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return SizedBox();
 ...
```